# Python Tkinter widget.place method does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code like

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x700+0+0")

#---------Backgroud of the main canvas-----`enter code here`-------

backGroundCanvas = Canvas(root,bg = 'white', width = 800, height = 600)
backGroundCanvas.focus_set()
backGroundCanvas.pack()

#--------------------------------------------------

#--------The other widgets out of the canvas--------

scoreLabel = Label(root, text = 'Your score is: 0', bg = 'red')
scoreLabel.place(x = 300, y = 750)
scoreLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But no matter how I change the parameter of the place method, the label always in the same place and can not be changed.I do not know why! Please help me , thanks a lot!

Comment: dont combine `.pack()` and `.place()`, use one or the other, in this case use `.place()` and then changing values will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TKinter there is three basic Geometry manager : Grid, Pack, Place.

You should try to avoid the use of place as often as possible using instead Grid or pack ( I personally consider that only grid is a good manager, but this is only my opinion).

In your code you are setting a position to your widget using place manager, and then give the control to the pack manager. Just remove the `scoreLabel.pack()` et voila!

NB : your application is 700px high, and you are trying to place your red label at 750px from the top, you're widget will be outside of the screen.

NBB : I strongly recommend the use of grid manager.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x700+0+0")

#---------Backgroud of the main canvas-----`enter code here`-------

backGroundCanvas = Canvas(root,bg = 'white', width = 800, height = 600)
backGroundCanvas.focus_set()
backGroundCanvas.pack()

#--------------------------------------------------

#--------The other widgets out of the canvas--------

scoreLabel = Label(root, text = 'Your score is: 0', bg = 'red')
scoreLabel.place(x = 300, y = 600)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and post some fact based reasoning ( code samples ) where your opinion-based recommendation hit an example, **where { pixel-absolute | widget-relative } services of `.place()` geometry manager have failed?** Thanks for clear and sound examples supporting your opinion

Comment: @user3666197: There have been no studies that I know of that show where `place` has failed. I would argue, however, that just about anyone who has spent any time at all maintaining a complex GUI in tkinter can tell you that absolute positioning is doing it the hard way. While I don't think place should be strictly avoided per se, `pack` and `grid` typically give you better behavior with fewer lines of code, and which is more maintainable. I think you would be hard pressed to find a single good tkinter (or tcl/tk) based GUI that used `place` for the majority of its layout.

Comment: Exactly my recommendation of use the grid manager instead of the place manager is to save you time and avoid you the boring task of calculate the pixel position of every widget. You can obviously realize the entire interface using place, though you are going to have a bad time. I personally use it when I want to create class of widget with particular design with for example a button that overlay a canvas or thing like that.

Comment: I quite like using the place geometry manager, after creating my own library for creating types of layout I find it faster and easier to understand that either grid or pack, though I haven't used pack very much. Agree if you just use raw place, but if you create macros to help with layout then even modifying layout becomes easy. But then again, I don't write applications for phones and tablets or that will resize on the fly. Mainly data entry and reporting in a production environment.